# How to use HTML application to display only centered image?

Tags: html, vbscript, hta

I am using a hta file as a splash screen, The image the hta file opens is called "Loading1.png" and is 478 x 50.  When making the window size and position in the hta file, the image is show with a white border and is off center.

What could be wrong with my code?

```
<html>
    <hta:application id="oHTA"
        border="none"
        caption="no"
        contextmenu="no"
        innerborder="no"
        scroll="no"
        showintaskbar="no"
    />
    <script language="VBScript">
        Sub Window_OnLoad
            'Resize and position the window
            width = 478 : height = 50
            window.resizeTo width, height
            window.moveTo screen.availWidth\2 - width\2, screen.availHeight\2 - height\2

        End Sub
    </script>
<body>
    <table border=0 width="100%" height="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle">
                <img src="Loading1.png"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I just want to display my image "Loading1.png" in the center of the screen with no borders or anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Loading1.png` image properties:

[image: Loading1.png properties]

The HTA application (note fine balancing ±1 pixel):

```
<html>
    <HTA:APPLICATION ID = "oHTA"
        BORDER          = "none"
        BORDERSTYLE     = "normal"
        CAPTION         = "no"
        CONTEXTMENU     = "no"
        SYSMENU         = "no"
        NAVIGABLE       = "no"
        INNERBORDER     = "no"
        SCROLL          = "no"
        SELECTION       = "no"
        SINGLEINSTANCE  = "yes"
        WINDOWSTATE     = "normal"
        SHOWINTASKBAR   = "no"
    />
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9">

  <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: red;  /*  ↓↓↓ merely for contrast ↓↓↓  */
        border-color:     red;  /*  ↑↑↑ merely for contrast ↑↑↑  */
        margin-top:      -1px;
        margin-left:     -1px;
        margin-bottom:   -1px;
        margin-right:    -1px;
    }
  </style>

  <script language="VBScript">
      Option Explicit
      Dim width, height
      width  = 478 -1                 '''  
      height =  50 -1                 ''' 
      Sub window_onload()
          CenterWindow width, height
      End Sub
      Sub CenterWindow( widthX, heightY )
          self.ResizeTo widthX, heightY 
          self.MoveTo (screen.availWidth - widthX)/2, (screen.availHeight - heightY)/2
      End Sub
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="Loading1.png"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Result (white background):

[image: white background]

Result (black background):

[image: black background]